# Java: How/Should I optimize a method with multiple IF statements?

Tags: java, optimization, gwt

The problem is less generic, than in subj. Here I have the *Builder* pattern for user's convenience and a method with multiple IFs. However each IF statement is a condition on one of the object's **non-final** field. There're no assignment operations to these fields within the body of the method under consideration as well, as no setters provided by the class's API. Example:

```
public class MyFormatter {
    public static class Builder {
        private final boolean notOptional;  // don't mind this one, just the Builder pattern
        private boolean optionalA, optionalB, optionalC;  // these would matter further
        private Builder optionalA() { optionalA = true; return this; }
        private Builder optionalB() { optionalB = true; return this; }
        private Builder optionalC() { optionalC = true; return this; }

        public Builder(boolean notOptional) {
            this.notOptional = notOptional;
        }

        public MyFormatter build() {
            MyFormatter formatter = new MyFormatter(notOptional);
            formatter.optionalA = optionalA;
            formatter.optionalB = optionalB;
            formatter.optionalC = optionalC;

            return formatter;
        }
    }

    private final boolean notOptional;
    private boolean optionalA, optionalB, optionalC;  // Not final

    private MyFormatter(boolean notOptional) {
        this.notOptional = notOptional;
    }

    protected String publish(String msg) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Here we go: a lot of IFs, though conditions "effectively never" change
        if (optionalA) {
            sb.append("something");
        }

        if (optionalB) {
            sb.append("something else");
        }

        if (optionalC) {
            sb.append("and something else");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Ok, now the questions are how much JIT-compiler can do to optimize this code, and if there's anything I can do to optimize it (some lazy initialization etc.).

p.s. (Harder question) Imagine this code being translated in JavaScript (by GWT), i.e. no JVM would be involved in executing/optimizing this method. What can a programmer do in this case to improve the performance?

Comment: "Java" is to "JavaScript" what "Ham" is to "Hamster". They're completely unrelated. Please don't tag [tag:Java] questions with [tag:JavaScript].

Comment: @Cerbrus To be fair, the follow-up question talks about transpiling Java to JavaScript.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Which should probably be a separate question altogether.

Comment: The real question is whether you have a performance issue at all. Don't optimize what isn't a proven bottleneck.

Comment: I wouldn't focus so much on Java -> JavaScript part (that's why it's originally under p.s.). This is a Java-related question.

Comment: @vitrums: Doesn't your IDE complain about `optionalA` being used as a variable name, and as a function name? Your code looks rather... confusing.

Comment: IDE Eclipse, and no it's perfectly fine to have the same names for fields and methods (even preferable in case of Builder pattern).

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. From the looks of it, all you _could_ do to make the `if` statements more readable, it reduce the whitespace around it. Remove the unnecessary `{}`, and maybe even move the `sb.append` behind the `if`, instead of under it.

Comment: This is a toy example. The real version in my project has way more lines within IF blocks as well as the number of IF blocks and optional variables correspondingly.

Comment: Then it seems to be as efficient as it gets.

Comment: On the other hand I could as well lazy-create a list of suppliers (List<Supplier<StringBuilder>>), where each supplier corresponds to one IF statement, and run through it within a loop. This way I avoid any conditions, but instead I make method calls, which can be or can be not (I'm not sure here) optimized by JIT-compiler (if we talk about JVM).

Comment: Again, this seems to be premature optimization. Note that an `if` translates to a conditional jump, which would also exist in any loop that you create (testing the loop termination condition), and method calls also include stack allocations. **Is this code causing a bottleneck in your program**?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The class presented in the original post is responsible for formatting the log messages. It is absolutely crucial for dev to see the real-time dynamics and each millisecond matter a lot. I found, that the amount of IF statements is proportional to the time this method works, i.e. the same amount of StringBuilder's job without any clauses is much faster (to be fair, it's because this is javascript/DOM, not JVM). But again, I got really curious of how this can be optimized if I face the same code pattern in pure Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is absolutely crucial for dev to see the real-time dynamics and each millisecond matter a lot.

That's it. Unless your devs can read many thousand messages per second, you're fine. The cost of

```
    if (optionalA) {
        sb.append("something");
    }
```

consists of two parts.

- The conditional branch and the appending. A mispredicted branch takes 10-20 cycles, i.e., up to `20 / 3` nanoseconds on a 3 GHz CPU. A correctly predicted branch is essentially free and because of the boolean being constant and the code being hot, you can assume that.
- According to the length of `"something"`, the appending may be more costly, but no details are given, so there's nothing to optimize.

I don't think the JIT will find something to optimize here. You could size your `StringBuilder` to gain a bit.

*All in all, it* is *premature optimization.*

> Imagine this code being translated in JavaScript (by GWT)

Modern browsers have an advanced JIT just like Java does. Due to Javascript being weakly typed, it can't be as fast, but it comes pretty close.

*Measure before optimizing, so you don't spend your time where the CPU does not.*

Comment: Thank you. On the part of optimization you seemed to give an exhausting answer. Now, just to clarify my point about real-time log. What devs might find important in messages is the amount of milliseconds the last operation took. Instead of manually tracking it with additional lines of code, they rely on timestamps of logger. But if they build a more detailed formatter (more clauses and longer StringBuilder), then the performance might erroneously seem to weaken in speed, while it's just that the logger worked longer.

Comment: @vitrums That's surely true. The measurement influences what gets measured and that's a problem. You can try: 1. Make it constant time by always doing all the work, even when not needed. This only applies when it's fast enough not to be a problem. Google for 'jmh blackhole` to avoid dead code optimization. 2. Make a toggle switching off the details used when measuring. This may be hard as without the details, you mayn't be able to find the relevant piece. 3. Make a toggle doubling the overhead, so you can measure twice and subtract it. +++ No solution is really good.